# JP Travel Joomla Template

Tags: css, templates, joomla

I have the JP Travel Joomla Template. Which css should I modify to change the background for the top left menu and the main menu?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://demo.joomlaplates.com/jp_travel/).
The main menu is in the `layout.css` in the `#suckerfish` class on line **84**.
And the top menu is in `menu.css` at the `#top .menu` class on line **96**.

Comment: @Elmer Tillet, this is correct, but I would personally add the CSS to override the background to a custom CSS file so that if the developer brings out a new release for the template and you update it, your changes won't get overridden ;)